# Riddle of the telephone

Tags: riddle

> What's shaped like a telephone, has three corners and spits far?

Clues:

> Two blondes, Confectioner's sugar.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Matthew Parker! I suggest you take the [site tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), it's a good way to familiarise yourself with how the site works (and you get a badge too).

Comment: What type of telephone does it have to be? Since the design of telephones are very diverse.

Comment: Note that quite a bit of information has been edited out of this puzzle - Namely that the author does not know the answer to the puzzle and is asking if anyone else does.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> A shower?

What's shaped like a telephone,

> The head of a traditional telephone is similar in shape to some showerheads [image: [enter image description here]

has three corners

> Corner shower trays typically have three corners with one curved edge [image]

and spits far?

> Yes.  But it depends on water pressure.

Two blonds

> Could be brass taps?  Or a pair of blondes in the shower?

Powdered sugar

> -Is showered over cakes?  I dunno...

Comment: Maybe it is that if you mix the pronunciation of "powdered" and "sugar" you can kind of get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

> A Banana

Hint response:

> Sweet white (confection sugar) fruit between yellow (blonde) peel.

Shaped like a telephone:

> Ring, ring, ring, ring, banana phone!

...has three corners...:

> Split a banana open. It has 3 segments, all triangular-like pieces fitted together.

...and spits far:

> At first I read it as "splits far" but perhaps in reference to cartoons (e.g. the old Warner Brothers cartoons) where the banana is squeezed/stomped on and it fires like a gun? Still thinking on this bit..